# Area of $x^{10}+y^{10}\leq 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

Whilst looking at someone's vector calculus problem, they mentioned that, making use of Green's Theorem, they had to express the line integral of the boundary of $x^{10}+y^{10}\leq 1$ in terms of its area. The thing is they gave you the area as computed with Mathematica to be $4\Gamma^2(11/10)/\Gamma(6/5)\approx 3.943.$

And I was wondering how you'd prove this:
$$\mathcal{A}=\iint_{x^{10}+y^{10}\leq1}dydx=2\int_{-1}^1\sqrt[10]{1-x^{10}}dx=\dfrac{4\Gamma^2(11/10)}{\Gamma(6/5)}.$$

Comment: It is a method due to Dirichlet;  it is in  Whittaker and Watson, A Course of Modern Analysis. First edition was 1902, on pages  191-193. I found an online scan ... let me see if I can find it again.  Well, this is the third edition, https://ia801601.us.archive.org/6/items/courseofmodernan00whit/courseofmodernan00whit_bw.pdf

Comment: page n8mbered 258, pdf page called 272

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Green’s Theorem? Do the line integral $$\frac12\int_C -y\,dx+x\,dy,$$ parametrizing $C$ by $x=(\cos t)^{1/5}$, $y=(\sin t)^{1/5}$.

Comment: We could also apply what you said:


Choosing $\mathbf{F}=x\boldsymbol{j}$, we get that
$$\iint_A (\partial_x F_y-\partial_y F_x)dydx=\iint_A dydx,$$

and by Green's theorem we know that is also equal to
$$\oint_{\partial A}\mathbf{F\bullet dr}=\oint_{\partial A}xdy$$
and by parametrizing $x$ and $y$ like you said, we get
$$\frac{1}{5}\int^{2\pi}_0 \cos^{\frac{6}{5}}t\sin^{-\frac{4}{5}}tdt,$$
which has somewhat the form of the beta function:
$$\mathfrak{B}(x,y)=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2x-1}\phi\sin^{2y-1}\phi d\phi.$$

And from here IDK how to proceed.

Comment: I am not sure why but when computing the integral numerically, I don't get what I'm supposed to...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can tackle a more general question: that of the unit $\ell^p$ ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. the volume of the body given by
$$
\{ (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid |x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p \le 1 \}
$$
Note that your case is $n=2$ and $p=10$.

Let $V_{n,p}$ denote the volume of this ball. Then, analogous to your transformation from a multi-integral to a single integral, we see
$$
V_{n,p} = 2 V_{n-1,p} \int_{0}^1 (1-x^p)^{(n-1)/p} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
To see this, note that
$$
|x_1|^p + |x_2|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p \le 1
\iff
 |x_2|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p \le 1 - |x_1|^p
$$
and rewrite as
$$
V_{n,p} = \int_{-1}^1 \mathrm{d}x_1 \int_{ \sum_2^n |x_i|^p \le 1 - |x_1|^p} \mathrm{d} x_2 \cdots \mathrm{d} x_n
$$
with the right integral as the volume of an $(n-1)$-dimensional ball.

Now, with the substitution of $u=x^p$, we see that
$$
x=u^{1/p} \qquad \mathrm{d}u = px^{p-1} \, \mathrm{d} x \qquad \mathrm{d} x = \frac 1 p u^{\frac 1 p - 1}
$$
and hence
$$
\int_{0}^1 (1-x^p)^{(n-1)/p} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac 1 p \int_{0}^1 u^{\frac 1 p - 1} (1-u)^{(n-1)/p} \, \mathrm{d}u
$$
The [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) is defined by
$$
B(x,y) := \int_0^1 t^{x-1} (1-t)^{y-1} \, \mathrm{d} t \equiv \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}
$$
so we hence see
$$
V_{n,p} = \frac 2 p V_{n-1,p} \cdot \frac{ \Gamma(\frac 1 p  ) \Gamma( \frac{n-1}{p} + 1 )}{\Gamma( \frac n p + 1 )}
$$
Apply the recursion property of the gamma function, $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$, to then get
$$
V_{n,p} = 2 V_{n-1,p} \cdot \frac{ \Gamma(\frac 1 p + 1  ) \Gamma( \frac{n-1}{p} + 1 )}{\Gamma( \frac n p + 1 )}
$$
This gives us a recursive relation; iterating backwards to $V_{1,p} = 2$, we then get the desired result of
$$
V_{n,p} = 2^n \frac{\Gamma^n(\frac 1 p + 1)}{\Gamma(\frac n p + 1)}
$$
With $n=2$ and $p=10$, we see your desired result:
$$
V_{2,10} = 4 \frac{\Gamma^2(11/10)}{\Gamma(6/5)}
$$

Comment: Very complete solution on your part: thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

This is a corollary to the relationship between the gamma and beta functions:$$
\mathrm{B}(x,y) \doteq \int_0^1 t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} dt = \frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}.
$$
To see this we use the substitution $u = t^n$ to find that $$
\int_0^1 (1-t^n)^{1/n}\,dt = \int_0^1 (1-u)^{1/n} u^{-1+1/n}\,du = 
\frac{1}{n}\mathrm{B}(1+1/n,1/n) = \frac{\Gamma(1+1/n)\Gamma(1/n)}{n \Gamma(1+2/n)} = \frac{\Gamma(1+1/n)^2}{\Gamma(1+2/n)}.
$$
The final step uses the identity $\Gamma(x+1) = x \Gamma(x)$.  Interestingly, if we expand this formula in powers of $1/n$ we find out how fast the area converges to that of the $2 \times 2$ square: $$
4 \frac{\Gamma(1+1/n)^2}{\Gamma(1+2/n)} = 4 - \frac{2\pi^2}{3n^2} + O(n^{-3}).$$

Comment: Really interesting and straightforward, thank you.